# cordova build Command failed with exit code EACCES

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, cordova-3

Cordova build failed with error code : EACCESS

```
$ cordova build android
Running command: /home/user/proj1/platforms/android/cordova/build 
execvp(): Permission denied
Error: /home/user/proj1/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code EACCES
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)

 ======================================   
     OS  : Ubuntu 14.04
     npm version: 1.4.16
     cordova version : 3.5.0-0.2.4
 ======================================
```

have added android platform to `proj1`
tried to re-installing `cordova` but did not work

Answer (score 78, accepted):

For some reason build is not currently an executable file. To fix that, open the terminal and enter the following commands:

```
$ cd <your-project-directory>/platforms/android/cordova
$ chmod a+x build
```

Comment: I had the a similar problem but with "platforms/android/gradlew". Tried running chmod on "gradlew" directory and that worked!

Comment: I also needed to do it on gradlew in the android folder to get it to build for Android.

Comment: Thank you! This appeared to me after macos update to 10.15 (catalina).

Answer (score 17):

You should add permission to two files:

Go to Cordova root directory and run:

```
chmod a+x platforms/android/gradlew
chmod a+x platforms/android/cordova/build
```

Comment: the gradlew permissions was the issue for me. updating permissions on just the cordova build file didn't fix my issue. not sure what caused it however. ty

Comment: this answer helped me out.

Answer (score 12):

This is a common PhoneGap problem.

Most of the time it has to do with permissions on the `build` folder and script file.

Try using: `chmod a+x` on them.

Comment: i feel your pain, truly, but downvoting for obvious reasons... cmon! try to be  bit more helpful!

Comment: Can you show how to use that chmod a+x line? Or do you just enter it in the parent folder and hit enter?

Comment: You have to `chmod a+x /directory/file` in order for it to work. See: http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/

Comment: I also needed to do it on gradlew in the android folder to get it to build for Android.

Answer (score 8):

My advice is to remove the `platforms` directory, and reinstall each platform.

```
$ cd <your-project-directory>
$ rm -r platforms  # -or- manually remove the directory
$ cordova platform add <platform>  # ios, android, ...
```

Running `chmod a+x build` (as suggested in the accepted answer) doesn't fix `cordova platform rm <platform>` permission issues. Safer (and easier) to restore each platform to it's default state, instead of hacking (and remembering) permission changes for individual files / directories.

Comment: safest solution

Answer (score 7):

To solve the EACCESS Problem please copy and save your platform custom icons / splashes / config.xml settings and delete the platform folder. after that run phonegap run android from your console again. it should work again. after that copy back the custom files / settings to the new platform folder.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was solved by removing the map /platforms/android. After that I added the platform again.

cordova platform add android

For me it worked out, but I think there are multiple reasons this error is shown..

**! Backup your icons  !**

Remember to backup your icons in /platforms/android/res/
Or copy the whole map as backup to be sure you don't lose your work...

Answer (score 5):

You could brute force it if you are an admin and just `sudo chmod -R 777 ./platforms/` from the project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to diagnose the problem here. Could you add more information to the problem description?

For what I can see, which is not too much, it is because one of the executables doesn't have the right exec permissions for your user (assuming you are on Ubuntu 14.04 per your output).

Ensure Android SDK Tools and Platform-Tools, as well as Oracle JDK and Ant, are in your PATH with the appropriate permissions. Otherwise, put more information here.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have same problems, solved it today after countless of trials and error. I have actually get BUILD SUCCESS to appear.
the thing is to change the environemnt variable..
**from**

> JAVA_HOME : c:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre 
>   PATH: c:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.x.x\bin

**to**

> JAVA_HOME : c:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.x.x\jre
>   PATH: c:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.x.x\bin

**NOTE**: the JAVA_HOME has to point to **JDK/JRE** (the jre child of jdk). I install both jre and jdk. it seems that I need to install both for the cordova-CLI to work on windows8.1.
I hope this helps.